# How many lines of code can be in a C++ function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function

How many lines of code can be in one C++ function? Is there a limit? I'm using MSVS 2013. My main function is huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no limit, but keeping maintainability in mind around 30 lines max. Should be used if possible.

Comment: Will a program run slower if it is say 1 function with 200,000 lines of code versus 100 functions with 2,000 lines each?

Comment: It will possibly run slow because of increased stack size and branching instructions (An IF starting at 10000th line, ending at 12400 line).

Comment: I prefer max 10-20 max LOC, but short functions really make code readability++ and maintainability++

Comment: @ChrisG Yes indeed, but too short isn't good either. Because debuggig code which jumps to a new function after every 10 lines can be a mess too. Depending on how the functions are divided ofcourse, if they clearly do something else then its okay, but if function A is core functionality of function B jt might be too much.

Comment: Parsing some XML files and it's hard to keep it under 30 LOC, but 30 LOC is a good cap to be under it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no upper limit as to how many lines of code your method should have. But you need to make sure that your function is doing only one thing.

From the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LpVCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=From%20time%20to%20time,%20a%20complex%20algorithm%20will%20lead%20to%20a%20longer%20routine,%20and%20in%20those%20circumstances,%20the%20routine%20should%20be%20allowed%20to%20grow%20organically%20up%20to%20100-200%20lines.&source=bl&ots=GGNkg9JlQL&sig=gUpW75rIY5UhuC8Z3dcvrSca4xc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZqdrU8PvLAhWCJSwKHQpHB6YQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=From%20time%20to%20time%2C%20a%20complex%20algorithm%20will%20lead%20to%20a%20longer%20routine%2C%20and%20in%20those%20circumstances%2C%20the%20routine%20should%20be%20allowed%20to%20grow%20organically%20up%20to%20100-200%20lines.&f=false):

> From time to time, a complex algorithm will lead to a longer routine,
>   and in those circumstances, the routine should be allowed to grow
>   organically up to 100-200 lines. (A line is a noncomment, nonblank
>   line of source code.) Decades of evidence say that routines of such
>   length are no more error prone than shorter routines. Let issues such
>   as depth of nesting, number of variables, and other complexity-related
>   considerations dictate the length of the routine rather than imposing
>   a length restriction per se.
>
> If you want to write routines longer than about 200 lines, be careful.
>   None of the studies that reported decreased cost, decreased error
>   rates, or both with larger routines distinguished among sizes larger
>   than 200 lines, and you’re bound to run into an upper limit of
>   understandability as you pass 200 lines of code.

Comment: I see, thank you. what about the main function, is it acceptable to have a few hundred thousand lines of code in the main function? what are the downsides to having one function perform many different operations?

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer:- As I said, `main` is also a function, so it would be better if you can break your `main` function and write the different operations in different functions and call it from your `main` that would be more readable and will be considered a good practice

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer:- As far as the downside is considered, the biggest one would be when you want to debug for a bug then it would be a nightmare to debug `200,000 lines of code`(*which you commented below*). Also it would be very less readable for future coders who will/may be working on it.

Answer (score 3):

The C++11 Standard Annex B states:

> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process. Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.

And goes on to list the following recommended minimums that may be more likely to be hit in a huge function (particularly if it's auto-generated):

> — Nesting levels of compound statements, iteration control structures, and selection control structures [256].
>
> — Identifiers with block scope declared in one block [1 024].
>
> — Characters in one logical source line [65 536].
>
> — Case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch statements) [16 384].
>
> — Handlers per try block [256].

So, you may prefer to check your implementation docs if you go beyond these recommended minimums.  Most compilers woudl either have much higher limits, or no arbitrary limits at all.

Comment: What do they mean by "minimums"? Shouldn't it maximum? What am I missing here?

Comment: @J'e these are minimum recommended maximums - so for example "Characters in one logical source line [65 536]" means a compiler could reasonably have a maximum of 65 536, but it's still fine of course for a compiler to have a maximum of say 1 000 000.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is too big (>60 code-statement lines, excluding comments/blank lines), then it is hard to understand and debug. It would be difficult to change the function. It would have too many variables, would need more of unwanted stack size because of variables.

Program must always be broken into pieces. Each function should do individual work. A `sort` function, for example, should not `filter`, or allow additional parameter to *optionally filter*. Moving ahead, the functional-decomposition should go into object level decomposition.

Read about **minimum coupling high cohesion**.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you advice. I'll just try to answer your question.

There is no upper (or lower) limit defined for the length of a function in the C++ standard. It is highly unlikely that in a lifetime of programming you could write a single function that would exceed the capacity of modern compilers, such as VS or GCC. I would expect the practical upper limit to be well in excess of 100,000 lines, and quite probably 1 million or more.

Of course you should not write functions so large, but one of the useful things you may want to do is write a program that outputs C++ code, which you then compile. In this case it would be not at all unusual to have a single function of considerable size.

Comment: Having large generated code files (thx for mentioning this) we are actually getting trouble with functions that have 16k+ lines. The compiler is an ARM compiler. Visual C++ still is doing well.